# Do we need to run 'repair' if new data center is added

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, repair

Consider my current Cassandra cluster is following,
DC1: 2 DC2: 2 each data center has 2 nodes and RF=2. Now i am adding 2 more data centers
DC1: 2, DC2:2 , DC3: 2, DC4 : 2. 
So is it required to run nodetool repair on new nodes in DC3 and DC4.
So far i read executing nodetool rebuild in the new DC is enough.

Also, i have one more query on when to run 'nodetool repair'.
Please advise me.

Answer (score 4):

As you are adding the new DCs once you have changed the NetworkTopology replication factor to include the new DC a rebuild should be fine just make sure to specify the source DC as on of the preexisting DCs.

Here are [detailed steps for adding a new DC](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/operations/ops_add_dc_to_cluster_t.html).

In general you should be running a repair every week if you have the default GC Grace settings.

Comment: Thanks. So when adding DC3, rebuild DC1 and rebuild DC2 must be run on all the nodes in DC3. Am i right?

Comment: Also one more question, Can we run repair on the nodes which has heavy read/write operations?

Comment: When you add DC 3 rebuild each node there targeted at DC 1 or 2 that's enough.

Comment: As for repairs they will need to be done regularly everywhere it will take tuning and addressed if you find issues as its own question.

Comment: Okay Thanks !!. So we can run repairs even if the node is loaded with read/write operations and we dont need to allocate any maintenance period to run repairs where the load will be less.

Comment: A repair will take days.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125965/discussion-between-dinesh-kumar-and-jeff-beck).

Comment: @DineshKumar  This might serve as some useful background reading on repair: http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/repair-in-cassandra